# Ubuntu server installation installing SSH

Tags: server

I have a Windows 10 laptop, do I need to install Ubuntu before I can install Ubuntu Server for managing SSH and web hosting?

Answer (score 2):

No .. Ubuntu Server is a full OS - just without Graphical user interface.